# laravel textbox disabled field mandetory

Tags: php, laravel-4

my textbox code

```
<tr valign="top">
<td>{{ Form::label('city', 'City:') }}</td>
<td colspan="3">
{{ Form::text('city', 'United States', array('class' => 'field','disabled')) }}
@if($errors->first('city'))<br/><span class="error">{{ $errors->first('city') }}</span>@endif
</td>
</tr>
```

model profile.php

```
public static $rules = array(
        'first_name' => 'required|Max:32',
        'city' => 'required|Max:1',
        );
```

already city fields have value united states , but still validation showing "The city field is required." , what mistake i did here.. any help frnds..

Answer (score 0):

You disabled that form field on the front side only!
Attribute `disabled` on `input` element tells user cannot edit or change its value.

Check your rules

```
public static $rules = array(
    'first_name' => 'required|Max:32',
    'city' => 'required|Max:1',
);
```

You still insist that `city` should be required. I assume you do not pass any value from form to validation checkpoint.  Check code over there.

Answer (score 0):

add `array('disabled')` in the end.

Like this : `{{ Form::select('colors', Colors::all(), $color, array('disabled')) }}`